# Request only returns the last list value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm having trouble to show a group with their specific installations

I have the following request method:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route ("groups")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetGroups()
{
  try
  {
    List<Groups> listGroups = new List<Groups>();

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(this.connectionString))
    {
      connection.Open();

      using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
      {
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandText = "select Groups.IdGroup, Groups.NameGroup, AttributeCloned.IdInstallation, AttributeCloned.NameInstallation " +
                                              "from Groups " +
                                              "join AttributeCloned " +
                                              "on Groups.IdGroup = AttributeCloned.IdGroup "+
                                              "where Groups.IdGroup = 1 "+
                                              "order by IdInstallation asc";

       SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

       Groups group = null;
       Installations inst = null;
       while (reader.Read())
       {
         group = new Groups();
         inst = new Installations();

         group.IdGroup = reader["IdGroup"] == DBNull.Value ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(reader["IdGroup"]);
         group.NameGroup = reader["NameGroup"] == DBNull.Value ? string.Empty : reader["NameGroup"].ToString();
         inst.IdInstallation = reader["IdInstallation"] == DBNull.Value ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(reader["IdInstallation"]);
         inst.NameInstallation = reader["NameInstallation"] == DBNull.Value ? string.Empty : reader["NameInstallation"].ToString();
        }

        group.installations.Add(inst);
        listGroups.Add(group);
      }
  }
  HttpResponseMessage Response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, listGroups.ToArray());
  Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
  return Response;
  }

   catch(Exception ex)
   {
     return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex.Message);
   }
 }
```

I expected to receive a JSON with the following structure:

```
"idGroup": 1,
"nameGroup": "Default group",
"installations": [
                  {"idInstallation": 1,
                   "nameInstallation": "Installation1"
                  },
                  {"idInstallation": 2,
                   "nameInstallation": "Installation2"
                  },
                  {"idInstallation": 2,
                   "nameInstallation": "Installation2"
                  }
                 ]
```

However, JSON is returning me with the last installation:

```
"idGroup": 1,
    "nameGroup": "Default group",
    "installations": [
                      {
                       "idInstallation": 3,
                       "nameInstallation": "Installation3"
                      }
                     ]
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: I think everything with `group` should be outside of the loop.

Comment: You are overwriting `inst` in the while loop on each iteration.

Comment: Place `group.installations.Add(inst);` inside the while loop.

Comment: @RahulSharma it helped me a lot, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your case, you would need to Add to the list inside your while loop:

`group.installations.Add(inst);`

Answer (score 1):

```cs
group.installations.Add(inst);
```

Above statement should be inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Provided that you receive the installations 1, 2, and 3 from your query correctly (they actually exist), you seem to be making a new group for each new installation you read in your while loop.

```
while (reader.Read())
{
   group = new Groups();
   inst = new Installations();
```

This would cause you to spread your 3 installations in group-1 into 3 different group objects.

Though this is just a guess, provided that I cannot see how you write out your JSON.